# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iconType') in render function - vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am migrating my vue application from vue 2 to vue 3. I am getting this error while deleting (**functional: true**) option from a functional component. In my vue 2 application,i was using render function by passing props,data and listeners as parameters. Now, i have gone through the official docs but not able to understand how to pass parameters? Here is my vue 2 render function.

```
render(h, {props, data,listeners, children = []}) {
    let moreIcons = {};
    let cType = props.iconType || props.type;
    if(!cType) {
        cType = props.picto ? 'picto' : 'line'; 
    }
    if (cType === 'picto') {
        moreIcons = moreIconsPicto;
    } else if (cType === 'line') {
        moreIcons = moreIconsLine;
    }
    let cColor ='';
    if (props.primary||props.prim) { cColor= 'primary'; }
    else if (props.point||props.pnt) { cColor= 'point'; }
    else if (props.default||props.dft) { cColor= 'default'; }
    else if (!!props.color||!!props.col) { cColor= props.color||props.col; }

    let cSize = '' ;
    if(props.large || props.lg) {cSize= 'large';}
    else if(props.medium || props.md) {cSize= 'medium';}
    else if(props.small || props.sm) {cSize= 'small';}
    else if(props.xsmall || props.xs) {cSize= 'xsmall';}
    else if(props.full) {cSize= 'full';}

    let customSize = props.iconSize || props.size;
    if(parseInt(customSize, 10)) {customSize = customSize + 'px';}

    let iconName = props.icon || children.default().text;
    let options = {
        class: [
            'ur-icon',
            'ur-icon--'+cType,
            cColor && 'ur-icon--'+cColor,
            cSize &&'ur-icon--'+cSize,
            props.spacing && 'ur-icon--spacing'
        ],
        style: {
            fontSize: customSize
        },
        on: listeners
    };
    if(data.class) {
        if(Array.isArray(data.class)) {
            options.class = options.class.concat(data.class);
        }
        if(typeof data.class === 'string' || typeof data.class === 'object') {
            options.class.push(data.class);
        }
    }
    if(data.style) {
        options.style = Object.assign(data.style, options.style);
    }
    let child = [];
    if (moreIcons[iconName] !== undefined) {
        options.class.push('more-icon__'+iconName);
        let svg = moreIcons[iconName];
        if(!props.focusable) {svg = svg.replace('<svg ','<svg focusable="false" ');}
        options.domProps={innerHTML:svg};
    } else {
        // 1. icon class
        options.class.push('fa-'+iconName);
        // 2. type class
        if     ( props.brand )   { options.class.push('fab'); }
        else if( props.fab)      { options.class.push('fab'); }
        else if( props.regular ) { options.class.push('far'); }/* pro only */
        else if( props.far )     { options.class.push('far'); }/* pro only */
        else if( props.light)    { options.class.push('fal'); }/* pro only */
        else if( props.fal)      { options.class.push('fal'); }/* pro only */
        else if( props.old)      { options.class.push('fa'); }/* font-awesome 4.0*/
        else if( props.fa)       { options.class.push('fa'); }/* font-awesome 4.0*/
        else { options.class.push("fas"); }
    }
    return h('i',Object.assign(data, options));
},
```

How to migrate it to vue 3 render function or need to use setup function? If i use setup function then how can i pass data and listeners as params?

Answer (score 1):

The `h` function should be imported from `vue` not used as parameter, I recommend to use the render function with setup hook as follows :

```js
import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    ...
  },
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    let moreIcons = {};
    let cType = props.iconType || props.type;
     ...
     ....
    return () => h('i',Object.assign(data, options));
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, how to pass that data param in setup ?

Comment: You should define data inside the setup hook using the composition api properties like `ref` and `reactive`  not using the `data` option

Comment: Actually i have tried with composition api's setup function. But, not able to figure out still ref and reactive in that function. Can you please elaborate your above answer with ref? It will be helpful for me.